# Alternative to xml for passing data between two differnt programs

Tags: c, xml

I am not even sure, if this is a right question to ask here.

I have two different programs, program1 sends data to program2 in an xml file. I was using mxml library (http://mxml.sourceforge.net/) for reading, writing and searching data in xml tree, initially it was working fine, when there were few nodes in the tree; but now it is getting more complex,the node count is close to 700K and the size of xml is more than 100MB. The time taken to read, write and search for data in xml is becoming complex.

Now I am thinking that the idea of using xml was wrong, and need to find another way to do this, Can you please suggest me better was to pass huge data structures from one program to other program (apart from sql, I was thinking about sql, but looking for a more optimum way).

Comment: 100 mb isn't that big. option 1. create your own binary file format

Comment: @self I was thinking an 100MB xml file was big, currently loading, searching the xml file is causing a huge overhead (approx 20% of the time is spent on it). What do you mean by my own binary file format? sorry, I am new to this, if possible can you please point me to some literature so I can get more info about it

Comment: how about using json or protobuf?

Comment: @Kishore I was looking at this link https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/, I only see API's for c++, java, python. can you please confirm if this supports 'c'?

Comment: @Naks, have a look at this https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-c/wiki/Main_Page

Comment: If both run on the same server what about a shared map filed ?

Comment: What kind of information is in the XML file? Would a shared storage system such as a database make more sense?